# Can't get controllers to respond in vnext rc1-final

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've recently updated a beta 6 vnext app to rc1-final, things are starting to work again, loosely.  The main issue is my controllers, I can't get them to respond to anything, for example, one controller 'test' has a get method called 'pop', normally I would run the app and be able to hit it in a web browser, but now I'm getting a status 0 response code, nothing back, no breakpoint it.

I'm using kestrel and my command in project.json is,

```
"kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

My Startup config methods are,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();
    var policy = new CorsPolicy();
    policy.Headers.Add("*");
    policy.Methods.Add("*");
    policy.Origins.Add("*");
    policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
    services.Configure<CorsOptions>(x => x.AddPolicy("anyone", policy));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any ideas how to even start debugging this?

---

Update:  Okay so the issue was down to me threadlocking the main thread and nothing to do with what I had first assumed, I was awaiting a task incorrectly which was preventing requests from making it to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Configure method replace

```
app.UseMvc();
```

with

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

You also have to add the following method in your Startup.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

Comment: Okay, I've done that, but the behavior is still the same.  Do I have to do anything to get it to use that entry point?  Also just tried with a new controller,

    [Route("foo")]
    public class FooController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("bar")]
        public ActionResult bar()
        {
            return (null);
        }

    }

and the route setup

app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}");
            });

Comment: It's a bunch of services with a demo site, the demo site isn't always displayed, IIS wants to display a site but it's not appropriate in this case.  It just starts and stops.

Comment: Used to work fine, it's since upgrading that it's stopped.  Can't get any controllers to function.

Comment: IIS works out of the box. Kestrel may need some additional configuration. I would try to make it work on IIS first and then on Kestrel. Also, try to remove the Route and HttpGet attributes from your controller and see what happens. Since you have declared your route in Startup you probably don't need these

Comment: Okay I fixed it, it was a thread lock, I had some code await a task on the main thread.  It's all working now. *phew*